# Fazer pesquisa dentro do input e abrir em outra página

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, input, algoritmo-de-busca, button

Olá, estou criando um projeto em meu curso de informática. Gostaria de saber a melhor maneira de fazer uma pesquisa no banco de dados dentro de um input, e abrir em outra página a pesquisa.

Obs: Estou usando php, usei input e criei um button para direcionar para a página que quero.

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque seu campo de pesquisa e botão dentro das tags

```
<form action="paginaParaAbrir.php" target="_blank" method="post">
//Aqui seu botao e campo de pesquisa

</form>
```

Ai é so montar a paginaParaAbrir.php

Lembrando que para receber o valor do campo use:

```
<?php
    $campo = $_POST['nomeDoSeuCampoDePesquisa'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar a sua consulta no banco de dados com base no input e abrir o resultado em outra janela, faça o seguinte:

Seu input deve estar dentro de uma tag `<form>` que tenha um atributo `target="_blank"`. Sua página vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```html
<form action="novaTela.php" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="txtPesquisa" id="txtPesquisa" />
  <inut type="submit" name="btnEnviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Neste exemplo, estamos enviando o input para a página novaTela.php. Você deve programar a chamada do banco de dados nesta nova página.

ARQUIVO novaTela.php:

```
<?php
    $txtPesquisa = $_POST['txtPesquisa'];
    echo "FAZER A CONSULTA NO BANCO DE DADOS";
?>
```

Para fins acadêmicos: o atributo `target` da tag `<form` permite atribuirmos os seguintes valores:
*_self*: Se nenhum valor for informado, _self será o valor padrão. Ele envia o formulário para a mesma página do formulário;

*_blank*: ele envia o formulário para uma nova página (informar qual página através do atributo `action`;

*_parent*: envia o formulário para a página que chamou nova janela;

*_top*: envia o formulário para a página que chamou o `frame`;

*framename*: envia o formulário para um `frame` específico;